# QProcess does not work

Tags: qprocess

I have the following code:

```
const char* argument = string1.c_str();   
QString arg(argument);   
QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);   
proc->start(arg);
```

The value of string1 is:
    ps -ef | grep "./scriptTest" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

The problem is that the QProcess doesn't execute the command. If I copy and paste the value of string1 in the console, the command is executed successfully.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either invoke a shell in order to run the shell pipeline, or only run `ps` and do the rest of the processing in your program.